# React flux reset store value on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, react-router

I have simple implementation of react and flux. i am creating new post with actions and stores but the problem that if the user going to another route and come back the **this.postAdded** still the same value.

The store:

```
class NewPostsStore {
  constructor() {
    this.title = '';
    this.body = '';
    this.postAdded = false;

    this.bindListeners({
      createPost: PostsActions.createPost
    });
  }

  createPost(res) {
    this.postAdded = res.add;
  }
}
```

The Action:

```
class PostsActions {
  getPosts() {
    $.ajax({
      url: url
    }).then((posts) => {
      this.dispatch(posts);
    });
  }
  createPost(post) {
     $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data: post,
      url: url
    }).then((res) => {
      this.dispatch(res);
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Blog.createActions(PostsActions);
```

The component:

```
export default React.createClass({
  mixins: [addons.LinkedStateMixin],
   getInitialState() {
    return NewPostStore.getState();
  },
   onChange() {
    this.setState(NewPostStore.getState());
   },
  componentDidMount() {
    PostsActions.getPosts();
    NewPostStore.listen(this.onChange);
  },
  componentWillUnmount() {
    NewPostStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
  },

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    PostsActions.createPost({
      title: this.state.title,
      body: this.state.body
    });
  },
  setMessage() {
    if(this.state.postAdded) {
      return <h5>success</h5>
    } else {
      return <h5>failed</h5>
    }
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" valueLink={this.linkState('title')} />
           <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Body" valueLink={this.linkState('body')}/>
           <button>Create</button>
        </form>

         {this.setMessage()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

How can i reset the state when go to other view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [recycle](http://alt.js.org/docs/recycle/) method that do this for you -

If you wish to reset a particular, or all, store’s state back to their original initial state you would call recycle. Recycle takes a splat of stores you would like reset. If no argument is provided then all stores are reset.

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
    NewPostStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
    alt.recycle(NewPostStore);
  }
```